# ASP.Net WebAPI has different content type in different user agents

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, user-agent

I am trying to learn ASP.Net WebAPI, and I am having a hard time figuring out what is going on. I created a small application that contains an action like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult Hello() 
{
    return Ok("Hi");
}
```

This works fine, so I look at it in the browser. I see:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">Hi</string>
```

This is using Chrome. I use an extension to see the content type and it is `text/xml`. I want to check things out further so I use Postman REST Client to test it. There I see: `"Hi"` and the content type is `application/json`. I am completely confused. I figured that Postman was just changing the content type, but to be sure I installed another REST client but it returned `application/json`. In Internet Explorer it attempts to download the result as a JSON file. What the heck is going on. Is there a way I can have a universal content type?

Comment: http://www.strathweb.com/2012/07/everything-you-want-to-know-about-asp-net-web-api-content-negotation/  Everything you ever wanted to know about WebAPI Content Negotiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web api can serialise responses to Xml or Json. It reads the Content-Type Http header to determine which one. Use fiddler to examine requests from the brower. Postman passes application/json as the content type by default - so you get the json response.

You can add the following code to your WebApiConfig file to remove the XML serialiser and it will always return json.

```
var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
    config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
```

Comment: Any way to stop IE from trying to download the response?

Comment: I don't know because I never use IE. But there's no reason to test web api responses on different browsers as the user-agent doesn't affect the response. (Unless you are specifically doing something user-agent specific). So just use chrome and/or postman.

Comment: you can modify the registry to enable IE to "browse in place" json content.... see http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/216175/View-JSON-in-Internet-Explorer